# "Mounting cifs URL not implemented yet" when I try to mount a samba share

Tags: mount, samba, netbeans, cifs

I have a server for development (Ubuntu 12.04). On that machine, I have a shared folder named "projects". I tried

`sudo mount -t smbfs smb://192.168.2.28/projects/myProject /mnt/myProject`

on my Ubuntu 11.10 and got the error:

```
Mounting cifs URL not implemented yet. Attempt to mount smb://192.168.2.28/projects/myProject.
```

How can I do to solve it? I need to mount the folder to use it with NetBeans.

Comment: Sounds like the samba server (192.168.2.28) isn't setup yet or doesn't have the proper ports open to allow it to connect. Can you run this command to make sure you see the proper ports open for samba connection: sudo nmap 192.168.2.28

Comment: @ruffEdgz The problem is not related to the server; this error message occurs before any network operations are performed. See my answer for details.

Comment: Good to know. Haven't needed to do this on my laptop yet so I will have to make sure it works on my current Samba server ;)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Since as the error message says CIFS URLs (starting with `smb://`) are not supported, you have to use the "classic" syntax to identify the server and share. Furthermore, you cannot mount a folder *within* a share as though it is a share--you should mount the share and then access the folder within it. You can make a symbolic link to the folder inside the share,  if necessary. Finally, when you run `smbmount`, `mount -t smbfs`, or similar remote mount commands as `root` (for example, with `sudo`), you need to specify the username on the server (unless it's actually `root`, which is unlikely and, if the server runs a Unix-like system, not recommended).

So first, you'll create a folder (mount point) for the share:

`sudo mkdir /mnt/projects`

(This is assuming you want to create it in `/mnt`. It's become more common to create all globally accessible mount points that aren't part of your Ubuntu system itself in `/media` instead of `/mnt` but it's fine to use `/mnt` if you like.)

Then use a command like this to mount the share:

`sudo smbmount //192.168.2.28/projects /mnt/projects -o user=USERNAME`

Replace **`USERNAME`** with the username on the Samba server that you need to log in as. You'll be prompted for your password. You can specify your password on the command-line too (with `-o password=PASSWORD`) but it will appear in cleartext in the Terminal and will go into your command history, so you probably don't want to do that.

You'll notice that I've used `smbmount` but `mount -t smbfs` or `mount -t cifs` (or `mount.cifs`) should work just as well, if you prefer.

Now `smb://192.168.2.28/projects`'s contents are accessible in `/mnt/projects`. If you need to be able to access the contents of `smb://192.168.2.28/projects/myProject` in `/mnt/projects/myProject`, you can create a symbolic link:

`sudo ln -s /mnt/projects/myProject /mnt/myProject`

**For readers of Ubuntu 12.10 and later:** You must use `mount.cifs` or `mount -t cifs` (`smbmount` and `mount -t smbfs` are no longer provided). The [cifs-utils](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/cifs-utils) [image: Install cifs-utils] package is required. These commands will work on earlier systems too.

Comment: On Ubuntu 13.04 I had to install the cifs-utils first: `sudo aptitude install cifs-utils`. Afterwards I was able to mount a share with this syntax: `sudo mount -t cifs //server/share /mnt/`

Comment: @GeraldSchneider Thanks, I've added mention of that to the answer.

Comment: Worked with me mount Windows 7 (host) folder in Kubuntu 13.04 inside VirtualBox (using a host-only adapter).

Answer (score 22):

In order to permanently mount your SMB share use the following procedure:

1. create a folder for mounting the share on (for example **/mnt/windows**):

   ```
   sudo mkdir [mount point]
   ```
2. Change its permissions

   ```
   sudo chown [username]:[username] [mount point]
   ```
3. Create a file containing your *domain* credentials (I use **/home/[user]/.smbcredentials**)

   ```
   username=[domain user]
   password=[domain password]
   domain=[domain]
   ```
4. Add the following line to **/etc/fstab**

   ```
   //[smb hostname]/[share name]/        [mount point]  cifs        credentials=[credentials file path],rw,uid=[user],user       0       0
   ```
5. Run (only once, on reboot this will happen automagically)

   ```
   sudo mount [mount point]
   ```

*Tested to work on Ubuntu 12.10*

Comment: What worked best for me was: `echo //192.168.1.1/c$/ /mnt/c cifs credentials=/home/user/.smbcredentials,rw,uid=1001,gid=1001,user 0 0 | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab` . Then to mount, I ran: `sudo mount /mnt/c`

Answer (score 1):

While the accepted answer is correct, you can now mount a folder within a samba share with help from 3 packages:

```
samba-client
samba-common
cifs-utils
```

These are CentOS base repo packages (sorry, no longer an Ubuntu user so can't check) but I'm confident there's something similar for Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 18.04 I mounted a shared smb directory directly via the filebrowser, no command line fiddling required.

- [Open the file browser, then click +Other locations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yV9bK.png)
- [Enter server address eg smb://shared.foo.ac.uk](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CXM6J.png)
- Click "Connect" and enter your credentials if necessary