# simple and easy way to sync folders over LAN

Tags: samba, lan, sync

**Summary:** i'm using Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop and on my desktop.  I need to sync my data between these computers. I don't want a backup utility - i need a two-way sync.

What i tried already:

Using a cloud (Dropbox, Ubuntu One) is not an option because there's too much data to sync (~50 GB, 12000 files) - even if i purchased extra space, sending all this over the internet would take forever.

**This task is really easy on Windows** - i can just use FreeFileSync and a shared network folder. *That's the user-friendliness i want.*

Unfortunately, FreeFileSync doesn't work well with my Ubuntu, and apparently it cannot recognize a samba share address (it's the only way of sharing folders that i know how to setup).

DirSync Pro looks promising, but it throws an error when i try to run it:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: dirsyncpro/DirSyncPro : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0

Maybe it's because i have wrong Java, but unfortunately DirSync doesn't say what precisely i need. (i tried installing Java Runtime Environment from [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java), but it didn't work).

I don't want a command line tool, because i need an interactive way to view and set which files should be synced and in which direction.

I've already looked at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3678/make-my-own-dropbox-ubuntu-one-server-at-home). From what i see, nothing there suits my needs. Maybe i've overlooked something, but i've already spent *a few frustrating hours* trying to find a solution, configuring dependencies etc. without success.

A simple, foolproof solution please?

Comment: Do you want to sync or is sharing ok?

Comment: Umm, i'm not sure what you mean, but sharing alone is not enough - i'm working independently on these two computers, and so i need a two-way sync. DaBam's answer seems to do what i need.

Comment: Working with a file from multiple locations is different than working with multiple copies of a file. If you only need to have a single copy of the file than an nfs or smb mount is all you need.

Comment: Ah, i understand what you mean.  Unfortunately, i need to have multiple copies of the files - sometimes the computers aren't connected, and sometimes it's very inefficient to work on some big files over the network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just mount the samba paths as regular directories (have a look at the "mount" command), then use FreeFileSync.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I recommend expanding this to explain how to mount Samba shares this way.

Comment: @DaBam, that's a nice idea. I've found an explanation how to mount samba shares [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/137011/how-to-mount-a-samba-shared-folder-ubuntu-x-ubuntu), and it worked. If noone writes a better answer, i'll mark yours as accepted - thanks!

Comment: Its easy to use but it comes with malware: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeFileSync

Comment: Synkron its opensource and also easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried Tonido? it's user friendly and even can sync with wi-fi and with smartphones and stuff. Has clients for Windows Mac and Linux, iOS and Android

Comment: I've downloaded deb packages from their website and installed them, but when i try to run the app nothing happens. Anyway, from what i see on the website the free account is only 2 GB - not enough :(

Comment: When you run the app it should send you to a internal webpage (http://127.0.0.1:10001) and you create an account for your computer. Later you can access a webpage they give you to gain access to your files.
I have tested and i have a personal cloud of 500 GB (my whole hard drive!) i can access from everywhere in the world, if my notebook is turned on.