# How to synchronise my files over LAN (Ubuntu/Windows, I'm a novice)

Tags: sync, lan

I am trying to synchronise my files (there is too much data to use a cloud service) between my netbook (windows XP) and my new ubuntu machine using a LAN cable.

I was pleasantly surprised when ubuntu was able to link straight to my netbook over the LAN.  I can see and access the shared files on it, but for some reason, copying them straight over in batches always leads to an error after a while.  Besides, I am likely to write on either machine, and need a proper sync.  I used Syncback on my old windows machine, which worked great.  If I am to switch to ubuntu like I hope, I'll need something as useful.

I have managed to install FreeFileSync and Samba.  FFS does not show the network path when you browse for folders (neither did syncbackup when I tried that).  Samba doesn't seem to see it either, not that I really know how to work it!

I haven't had any joy with several hours of internet searching... could anyone help please?  I am a linux novice and any instructions, especially ones using the terminal, would need to be pretty idiot-proof as I have no prior knowledge!

This questions related pretty closely to this one [simple and easy way to sync folders over LAN](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253193/simple-and-easy-way-to-sync-folders-over-lan) but of course it said you can't respond to it to ask for further help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
First, map the Linux share (Samba) into your Windows XP machine as follows:

- Open file explorer (Right-click Start and click explore):
- click Tools (drop-down menu)
- click Map Network Drive
- Enter the path for your share \\ubuntubox\shareName and select a drive letter to map
- Click the link Connect using a different user name and enter user credentials (if required)
- Click finish

Second, install [**FreeFileSync**](http://sourceforge.net/projects/freefilesync/). With FreeFileSync, you can sync your Windows XP files to the target map drive/folder accordingly.

Comment: Ah, install sync on the WINDOWS machine!  This is exactly why I need to stop, take a break and think laterally from time to time!

With a few hiccups probably due to my netbook, I now have a synchronisation program working, thank you!

Comment: Went for Syncback in the end as my known program.

All the same, my optimism is a bit shaken by ubuntu's inability to do this, and by its "invalid argument" crashes in straight-copying files over...

Comment: No, I spoke too soon!  It has failed to copy over a thousand files, and Ubuntu is reporting a systems error.