# How to automount user homes from MS Server via sss

Tags: 14.04, automount, cifs, active-directory

I'd like to make an Ubuntu box member of an AD and automount home directories during login from a Samba server.

I managed to join the AD the realmd way. So I can look-up users and their passwd lines.

But I failed to automount the user homes. What I did so far:

1. Add autofs to services in `sssd` config
2. Create an automount config `auto.home`: `* -fstype=cifs,rw,sec=krb5 ://myserver/&`

I just couldn't find any instructions how to integrate autofs with realmd/sssd approach in Ubuntu 14.04. Any hints?

When I try it manually as root user (`sudo -s`)

```
kinit myuser
mount -t cifs -o rw,user=myuser,sec=krb5 //myserver/myuser /home/myuser
```

I get: `Permission denied`. Which may be due to the fact that sssd uses some hashing algorithm to calculate a user ID, while the Samba server uses some enumeration.

So actually want sssd to handle all credential stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount them automatically at system startup by adding entries to fstab. You have to take care to provide your user credentials, which can be done via a file in your home dir.
Please find the details at:
["Mounting cifs URL not implemented yet" when I try to mount a samba share](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137011/mounting-cifs-url-not-implemented-yet-when-i-try-to-mount-a-samba-share)

Comment: Sorry, but my problem is way more complex. I'm looking for integration with sssd.