# FreeFileSync - NAS - permissions

Tags: permissions, mount, fstab, sync, nas

I'm new in linux so forgive me if I make obvious mistakes. 
I'm trying to figure out how to get my laptop synced with my (Synology) NAS.

I have installed FreeFileSync. It works perfect between folders on my laptop and from NAS to laptop.

I have mounted my shared folder with following line in `/etc/fstab`

`//192.168.10.111/Shared /media/shared cifs username=XXX,password=YYY,domain=WORKGROUP,rw,uid=1000,gid=1000 0 0`

I've uses several mounting options, as with or without `umask=0222,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777`

If followed the instructions as described [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/137011/mounting-cifs-url-not-implemented-yet-when-i-try-to-mount-a-samba-share).

I've tried with

- `sudo chown kasper:kasper /media/shared`
- `sudo chmod 777`
- `sudo chmod -R 777 /media/shared`

BUT in all cases I get the following error code in FreeFileSync for the files to be transfered to the NAS:

```
errorcode 13: Permission denied [chown]
```

When I do it manually (copy/paste files and folders to mounted folder) everything works fine. It seems that FreeFileSync does not have the correct permissions, but I don't find a way to change it.
I hope somebody can help me out. It took me a lot of hours already without any difference.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does `touch /media/shared/somefile` works from  terminal?

Comment: bash: /media/tinka/test/TESTEN/waarom: Permission denied (shared was an example, tinka is the real folder.) So - after 'touch' file, i've got permission denied

Comment: so it is permissions issue, not FreeFileSync

Comment: That's what I thought, but I cannot solve the permission problem, and as user (probably I've more rights) I do not face the same problem

Comment: UPDATE: because i did not know the meaning of the 'touch' command I looked it up.  The first time I tried to touch an existing file. If I do it with a new 'somefile' (as you said) it created an empty 'somefile'. So it is not a permissions issue?

Comment: `touch` is often used for creation of new empty file. If user has write permission to some directory, it creates file.

Comment: Are you sure that user has id=1000? Which `id` (only number) your `/media/shared` users have?

Comment: kasper@XXXXX ~ $ id -u kasper
1000

Comment: kasper@XXXXX ~ $ ls -l /media/tinka/test
total 0
drwxrwxrwx 3 kasper kasper 0 jan  9 21:47 Linux Leren
drwxrwxrwx 2 kasper kasper 0 jan 10 15:50 TESTEN

Comment: kasper@XPS-L502X ~ $ id -g kasper
1000

Comment: It seems I got it. You may try to go to FreeFileSync *Options* and uncheck here two checkmarks - *File-safe copy* and *Copy file access permissions* (the last one may be the problem).

Comment: you're a hero! thanks a lot!! this worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mount options are correct.

The problem is between file-system and FreeFileSync.

Go to FreeFileSync, *Options* and uncheck here two checkmarks - *File-safe copy* and *Copy file access permissions* (the last one may be the problem).